# Google chrome session restore trouble

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, bookmarks, session

I recently copied the whole folder of user data (that contains default and the other files) from my old laptop (I sold it) and pasted it in the same folder on my new laptop, I opened chrome and it loaded my bookmarks and only the first opened tab in my previous session and did not load the rest of the tabs.

How can I restore the previous sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Stop depending on Chrome’s unreliable built-in session-restore function and use a proper [session-management extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/session).

In the meantime, you can use a program like [Strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) to scan the `Current Session` and `Last Session` files for the URLs of the tabs you had open. With a little luck, you’ll be able to get a list and with some time and effort, you’ll be able to weed out the cruft and narrow down the output from `strings` to just the URLs you want.

1. Make a *copy* of the `Last session` and `Current Session` files to a temporary folder
2. Copy/extract the `strings` program to that folder
3. Open a command-prompt at the folder
4. Run these command (make sure to use the correct number of `>` as below):

   ```
   strings "last session" > urls.tmp
   strings "current session" >> urls.tmp
   find /i "http" urls.tmp > urls.txt
   ```
5. Close the command-prompt
6. Delete `urls.tmp`
7. Open `urls.txt` and weed out the URLs you don’t want